# using an IN parameter from a local table in an Openquery() call

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert records from a linked server into a local database. Something like this

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LocalTable]
           ([PORT]
           ,[new_ID]
           
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY("linked-server",'SELECT 
    ''remotePort'' [PORT]
      ,[Row ID] [new_ID]
  FROM [remoteDB].[dbo].[remoteTable]
  where [Row ID] NOT IN ('SELECT DISTINCT [new_ID] FROM [dbo].[LocalTable]')')
```

the query that I have so far is.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @string = 'SELECT DISTINCT [new_ID] FROM [dbo].[LocalTable];'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY("linked-server",''SELECT 
    ''''remotePort'''' [PORT]
      ,[Row ID] [new_ID]
  FROM [remoteDB].[dbo].[remoteTable]
  where [Row ID] NOT IN ('+ @STRING+');'')'

INSERT INTO [dbo].[LocalTable]
           ([PORT]
           ,[new_ID]

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

and I get this error

```
OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "linked-server" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name '[dbo].[LocalTable]'.
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It is possible to do directly without any use of `OPENQUERY`, though performance greatly depends on which side of the table the optimizer decides to remote: `SELECT * FROM [linked-server].remotedb.dbo.remoteTable where [Row ID] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [new_ID] FROM dbo.localtable)`. Doing the `DISTINCT` as a separate query to create a temp table first may be better. Approaches with constructing the `IN` list through string concatenation are also possible, but what you're doing now is just inserting the query instead of its results.

Comment: thanks. that does work. that is actually how I initially wrote the query but got so many `invalid object` errors in the query editor that I didn't bother to run it. then got sucked into the `openquey()` rabbit hole.